# Why jQuery object has a property, but hasOwnProperty says it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can read `className` property, but `hasOwnProperty` returns `false`. There is something I missed.

Comment: please read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty .....className property might be inherited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object that you're inspecting isn't a jQuery object: it's a DOM node. As such, it's inheriting the `className` property from farther up the tree (from `Element`, I believe). Since `className` is inherited, `hasOwnProperty` returns false as `hasOwnProperty` does not traverse the prototype chain.

From the question "Is there a way to check if an object has an inherited property?" below: inherited properties like `className` above [would appear in that object's prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

In the DOM node example from the question:

```
$(".comment")[0].hasOwnProperty('className'); // -> false because className comes from the prototype chain.

'className' in $(".comment")[0].__proto__; // -> true: className is inherited from up the chain
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if a object has an inherited property?

Comment: Updated my answer with a bit of research I did.